# C# Encoding to UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, html-entities, html-encode

I'm building a page in C# and I'm getting a cell value from `GridView1` with a code and I'm receiving this:

```
Tend&#234;ncias de Desfiles
```

How can I convert it to this:

```
Tendências de Desfiles
```

...using C#?
I tried it:

```
categoria = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(row.Cells[1].Text));
```

But don't work so please, help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode your text:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string encodedText = "Tend&#234;ncias de Desfiles";

        string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedText);

        Console.WriteLine(decodedText);
    }
}
```